# Notification not working in IOS and no sound When notification is received but vibration works

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created Flutter application using firebase for notification after integration of firebase for both IOS and android.

Notification only works in android but with no Sound

when notification is send from firebase console to android it works
But not for IOS there is no notification in iOS physical device

The issue is with iOS device i am not able to figure out how to solve this issue

Please guide me what to do if i have share any file do let me know which file i have to share

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
   • No issues found!
```

main.dart

```
import....

const iOSLocalizedLabels = false;

/// Create a AndroidNotificationChannel for heads up notifications
AndroidNotificationChannel channel;

/// Initialize the FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin package.
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

//Device Information Plugin
DeviceInfoPlugin deviceInfo=DeviceInfoPlugin();

// Global Key for Navigating during Notifications
GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey=GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

Map phoneInformation={};

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async
{
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  ///For supporting iOS 14+ phone with new updates
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  print('Handling a background message ${message.messageId}');
}

Future<void> main() async
{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterAppBadger.removeBadge();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Set the background messaging handler early on, as a named top-level function
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  if (!kIsWeb)
  {
    channel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel', // id
      'High Importance Notifications', // title
      'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
      importance: Importance.high,
    );
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    /// Create an Android Notification Channel.
    /// We use this channel in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file to override the
    /// default FCM channel to enable heads up notifications.
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
    /// heads up notifications.
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
    );
    ///Added new
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    /// to check the authorization of the application
    print('User granted permission');
  }

  if(Platform.isIOS)
    {
      IosDeviceInfo iosDeviceInfo=await deviceInfo.iosInfo;
      Map<String,String> data=
      {
        "name":iosDeviceInfo.name,
        "isPhysicalDevice":iosDeviceInfo.isPhysicalDevice.toString(),
        "uniqueId":iosDeviceInfo.identifierForVendor
      };
      phoneInformation=data;
      print("----------- $data");
    }
  else
    {
      AndroidDeviceInfo androidDeviceInfo=await deviceInfo.androidInfo;
      Map<String,String> data=
      {
        "name":androidDeviceInfo.device,
        "isPhysicalDevice":androidDeviceInfo.isPhysicalDevice.toString(),
        "uniqueId":androidDeviceInfo.androidId,
      };
      phoneInformation=data;
      print("-----------$data");
    }
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget{}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
// import UIKit
// import Flutter
// import Firebase
// @UIApplicationMain
// @objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
//   override func application(
//     _ application: UIApplication,
//     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
//   ) -> Bool {
//     FirebaseApp.configure()
//     GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
//     //GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
//    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
//     UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
//    }
//     return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
//   }
// }



import UIKit
import Flutter
import FirebaseMessaging
import Firebase // Add this import
@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, MessagingDelegate  {



  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

  

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
    
    //added new comment
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

       Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
       super.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)
     }
}
```

info.plist

```
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled</key>
    <false/>
```

At Splash Screen

```
  Future<void> setToken(String token) async
  {
    print('FCM Token:--- $token');
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.setString("FCM_token", token);
  }
  askPermission() async
  {
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.requestPermission(
    announcement: true,
    carPlay: true,
    criticalAlert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );



  @override
  void initState()
  {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    FlutterAppBadger.removeBadge();
    askPermission();
    Timer(Duration(microseconds: 1000), () {setState(()=>_Bigger = true);});
    startTime();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message)
    {
      RemoteNotification notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb)
      {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
            notification.hashCode,
            notification.title,
            notification.body,
            NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                channel.id,
                channel.name,
                channel.description,
                // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
                //      one that already exists in example app.
                icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
              ),
            ));

        FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message)
        {
          print('A new onMessageOpenedApp event was published!');
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Home.dart

```
  @override
  void initState()
  {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message)
    {
      if(message.notification.body.contains("requested")==true && widget!=AppNotificationVC())
        Navigator.pushNamed(navigatorKey.currentState.context,'/AppNotificationVC');

    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message)
    {
      print('Notification /Message open when click on it');
      if(message.notification.body.contains("requested")==true && widget!=AppNotificationVC())
        Navigator.pushNamed(navigatorKey.currentState.context,'/AppNotificationVC');
    });

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async
    {
     ....
    });
  }


 openNotificationCashpotAPI(String cashpot_id) async {...}

 notificationBadgeAPI() async{...}

  openUsernotificationAPI() async{...}
```

Comment: Have you uploaded APNs authentication key to Firebase? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#upload_your_apns_authentication_key

Comment: issue is i am getting no sound while receiving notification can you please help me out @user18309290

Comment: For both Android and iOS?

Comment: Yes for both @user18309290

Comment: Try to add a sound field to a message payload: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref.

Comment: I have if you look at above code

Comment: my notification sound work on the android but not on the ios

Comment: I have read here that not all audio file formats are supported by iOS. might this be your problem? https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW10

Comment: This is the part from the article that I meant. ```Local and remote notifications can specify custom alert sounds to be played when the notification is delivered. You can package the audio data in an aiff, wav, or caf file. Because they are played by the system-sound facility```

Comment: This article may help you: https://medium.com/@dmennis/the-3-ps-to-custom-alert-sounds-in-ios-push-notifications-9ea2a2956c11

Comment: Did you find a solution? If yes then please update here.

Comment: facing the same issue, any update guys?

Answer (score 4):

An important point; when you send notification manually, send sound parameter as well. Here is what an example notification request body looks like:

```
{
 "to" : "...",
 "notification" : {
     "priority": "high",
     "body" : "Example body",
     "title": "Example title",
     "sound": "default"
 },
 "data" : {
     ...
 }
}
```